# How to create client proxy without svcutil or add service reference in wcf?

Tags: wcf

How can I create a client proxy without svcutil.exe or add service reference in wcf?
I want to create a client proxy at compile time.

Comment: Do you need to create it at runtime, or at compile time, or in the IDE? Can you say what you're trying to accomplish? Otherwise you'll get answers which will not accomplish your goals.

Comment: Do you know the contract in advance? i.e. do you perhaps have the service interface as code?

Comment: Call me crazy, but why would you place a bounty and then fail to respond to questions? I suspect you'll get more out of SO if you help people to help you... they are asking questions because it is important for giving an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have access to the service contract (the IService interface) in a separate DLL, you can add a reference to that service contract DLL and then do something like:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9000/YourService")

ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, address);
IService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

and then you have your programmatically created proxy, which you can now use as you wish.

Comment: Does the `ChannelFactory` need a new `Binding` object every time?  Or should it be fine to create the binding and endpoint address once, and use them to create `ChannelFactory`s?

Comment: @epalm: you can definitely keep the binding and endpoint objects around and use them multiple times - no problem.

Answer (score 7):

This might not be what you are looking for, but it's pretty interesting.

Vipul Modi has a library that allows you to call WCF services after downloading their WSDL, all at runtime.

[Vipul Modi's library (latest version)](http://blogs.msdn.com/vipulmodi/archive/2008/10/16/dynamic-proxy-and-memory-footprint.aspx)

Allows you to do this kind of thing:

**Create the ProxyFactory specifying the WSDL URI of the service.**

```
DynamicProxyFactory factory = new DynamicProxyFactory("http://localhost:8080/WcfSamples/DynamicProxy?wsdl");
```

**Browse the endpoints, metadata, contracts etc.**

- factory.Endpoints
- factory.Metadata
- factory.Contracts
- factory.Bindings

**Create DynamicProxy to an endpoint by specifying either the endpoint or 
   contract name.**

```
DynamicProxy proxy = factory.CreateProxy("ISimpleCalculator");
```

//OR

```
DynamicProxy proxy = factory.CreateProxy(endpoint);
```

**Invoke operations on the DynamicProxy**

```
double result = (double)proxy.CallMethod("Add", 1d ,2d);
```

**Close the DynamicProxy**

```
proxy.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to code generate (or use a configuration file full of WCF specifics).

First create the interface defining the service (`[ServiceContract]`) with any supporting data contracts in an assembly separate from the service implementation.

Reference the interface assembly in the client assembly.

Then need to create a client proxy, for `IMyService`:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
ChannelFactory<IMyService> chanFac = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endpoint);
IMyService clientProxy = chanFac.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: Sounds like a solution that I happen to use in one of my web services. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have been using since wcf was introduced:
In an infrastructure assembly:

```
   internal class PerCallDisposeRealProxy<T> : RealProxy where T : class
{
    private readonly Binding _binding;
    private readonly EndpointAddress _endpointAddress;

    private static string EndpointName
    {
        get 
        {
            string endpointName = typeof(T).Name;
            if (endpointName.StartsWith("I"))
            {
                endpointName = endpointName.Substring(1);
            }
            return endpointName;
        }
    }

    internal PerCallDisposeRealProxy()
        : base(typeof(T))
    {            
    }

    internal PerCallDisposeRealProxy(Binding binding, EndpointAddress endpointAddress)
        : base(typeof(T))
    {
        if (binding == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("binding");
        if (endpointAddress == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("endpointAddress");

        _binding = binding;
        _endpointAddress = endpointAddress;
    }

    private ChannelFactory<T> CreateChannel()
    {
        if (_binding != null && _endpointAddress != null)
            return new ChannelFactory<T>(_binding, _endpointAddress);
        else
            return new ChannelFactory<T>(EndpointName);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage message)
    {
        if (message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("message");

        //Extract method info
        var methodCall = message as IMethodCallMessage;
        Debug.Assert(methodCall != null);
        MethodInfo methodInfo = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;
        Debug.Assert(methodInfo != null);

        T channel = null;
        ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = null;
        try
        {
            //setup channel
            try
            {
                channelFactory = CreateChannel();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Invalid endpoint configuration, make sure there is a servicemodel endpoint defined in configuration with the name {0}", EndpointName), ex);
            }
            channelFactory.Open();
            channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

            object result = methodInfo.Invoke(channel, methodCall.InArgs);
            return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
        }
        catch (FaultException faultException)
        {
            string msg = "FaultException: " + faultException.Message;
            MessageFault fault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
            if (fault.HasDetail)
            {
                System.Xml.XmlReader reader = fault.GetReaderAtDetailContents();
                if (reader.Name == "ExceptionDetail")
                {
                    ExceptionDetail detail = fault.GetDetail<ExceptionDetail>();
                    msg += "\n\nStack Trace: " + detail.StackTrace;
                }
            }
            return new ReturnMessage(faultException, methodCall);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException targetInvocationException)
        {
            return targetInvocationException.InnerException != null ? new ReturnMessage(targetInvocationException.InnerException, methodCall) : new ReturnMessage(targetInvocationException, methodCall);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return new ReturnMessage(exception, methodCall);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (channel as IClientChannel != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    (channel as IClientChannel).Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        (channel as IClientChannel).Abort();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    (channel as IClientChannel).Dispose();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            try
            {
                ((IDisposable)channelFactory).Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}

    public static class ClientProxyFactory
{
    public static T CreateProxy<T>() where T : class
    {
        return CreateProxy<T>(ProxyType.PerCallChannel);
    }

    public static T CreateProxy<T>(ProxyType proxyType) where T : class
    {
        return CreateProxy<T>(proxyType, null, null);
    }

    public static T CreateProxy<T>(ProxyType proxyType, Binding binding, EndpointAddress endpointAddress) where T : class
    {
        switch (proxyType)
        {
            case ProxyType.PerCallChannel:
                PerCallDisposeRealProxy<T> proxy = null;
                proxy = binding == null && endpointAddress == null ? new PerCallDisposeRealProxy<T>() : new PerCallDisposeRealProxy<T>(binding, endpointAddress);
                Debug.Assert(proxy != null);
                object transparentProxy = proxy.GetTransparentProxy();
                Debug.Assert(transparentProxy != null);
                Debug.Assert(transparentProxy is T);
                return transparentProxy as T;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Did not implement proxytype:" + proxyType);
        }
    }
}

    public enum ProxyType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// PerCall indicates a proxy that will create a channel pr. proxy method call and dispose of it before returning.
    /// </summary>
    PerCallChannel
}
```

And call site (in the service agent or whereever you want to call the external service from:

```
 INumeralConverterService proxy = ClientProxyFactory.CreateProxy<INumeralConverterService>();
 string result = proxy.DecimalToRoman(i);
```

Given the ServiceContract (and datacontracts) defined in yet another asssembly, here simply:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface INumeralConverterService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Decimal RomanToDecimal(string roman);

    [OperationContract]
    string DecimalToRoman(Decimal @decimal);
}
```