# how to Create object of the proxy class of wcf?

Tags: wcf, http

i want detail procedure to Create object of the proxy class of a WCF service whose i have only URL and parameter along with method() name.i have only limited resource as i have service URL ,parameter and name of the method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1086703/440030

Comment: i want a clear step by step description as i new at this ...!